# Using trademark as a name in a book?

Tags: copyright, trademark, fair-use

I am writing a childrens book and a character in it is supposed to be called Google. Is that legal? I am only using the word 'google' and not the colors, font etc that the word is written on the actual site. Mr. google knows everything about everyone :)

Comment: Related: [Can you trademark a proper noun from a work of fiction?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/can-you-trademark-a-proper-noun-from-a-work-of-fiction), [Using copyrighted or trademarked names for different ideas in fiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/19088/using-copyrighted-or-trademarked-names-for-different-ideas-in-fiction)

Comment: Could go either way. Google is, after all, a preexisting word in the English language before it was a company name.

Comment: The famous example would be from Douglas Adams, "Hitchhiker's Guide To the Galaxy" which has a character "Ford Prefect" named after a trademarked car model. That was satire, however, so special considerations applied.